# How to query for a selection within a duration where their respecitve previous ones have a null column

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a table with

```
email_id | email | called_at | created_at
```

Email is not unique so we can save as many emails as possible.

I want to query all the emails 1) within the last hour, 2) if we ever created such emails in the past, its called_at is null. As long as we ever called this email, we don't want to include this email in the list.

I tried something

```
SELECT
    e.*
  FROM emails e
  WHERE e.created_at > now() - 1.hour
    AND e.created_at < now()
    AND called_at IS NULL
```

But this only gives me those with NULL called_at, putting no restrictions on past called_at.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: what is the exact output of your statement? why you tagged `psql`?

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)